# Strange inconsistency between CPython and IronPython regarding zip file reading

Tags: python, ironpython

Please, observe:

**CPython:**

```
PS Z:\dev\poc\SDR> python
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Nov 27 2010, 17:19:03) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from zipfile import ZipFile
>>> z=ZipFile('d:/aaa.zip')
>>> input=z.open(z.namelist()[0])
>>> next(input)
'aaa,bbb\n'
>>> next(input)
'123,456\n'
>>>
```

**IronPython:**

```
PS Z:\dev\poc\SDR> ipy64
IronPython 2.7.1 (2.7.0.40) on .NET 4.0.30319.225
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from zipfile import ZipFile
>>> z=ZipFile('d:/aaa.zip')
>>> input=z.open(z.namelist()[0])
>>> next(input)
b'aaa,bbb\n'
>>> next(input)
'123,456\n'
>>>
```

Notice that IronPython displays the first line as `b'aaa,bbb\n'` whereas CPython does `'aaa,bbb\n'`. This difference is extremely important, because the former is just bytes whereas the latter is a string.

How can I make IronPython treat the first line as a string as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer:

```
str(next(input))
```

Longer answer: It's pretty weird that the first in is bytes but the second is a string. It's probably just a bug. Can you please [open an issue](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/WorkItem/Create) with a self-contained reproduction?

Comment: Thanks! I'll schedule it for 2.7.3, but no promises.

Answer (score 0):

This does look strange, but in python 2.7, a regular string *is* a byte string. In fact, `byte()` is a synonym for `str`. And if you print `repr(bytes("hello"))` you will see `'hello'`, not `b'hello'`.  In python 3 of course that's another story.

In short, you *are* getting a byte string in CPython already, so I believe there's no actual problem. (I'd certainly check if something is broken before spending more time trying to "fix" it). I don't use IronPython, but I have read that it uses unicode as the default type for strings (like Python 3). I'm concluding that `b'string'` in IronPython means the same thing as `'string'` in CPython 2 (and `'string'` means the same thing as CPython's `u'string'`).

Comment: Note, that both IronPython and CPython display the second line the same. Besides, both python flavors should adher to the same specification - if one returns a string, the other should return a string as well, no matter the internal representation (Ascii or Unicode) as long as there is a conversion between the two.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. NOW I see what you meant. IronPython is returning one bytestring and one regular. I saw some discussion about this in the forums, but I'm not sure what the conclusion was.

Comment: Here it is. Apparently the use of the python 3 character model exposes an inconsistency in some python modules, and this thread at least suggests just living with it: http://mail.python.org/pipermail/ironpython-users/2010-November/013973.html